# I am installing new ubuntu in my system which one should I choose 16.04 or 17.10?

Tags: 16.04, 17.10

I am setting up a new ubuntu system. I want to know which version should I choose to go with. My usual work is to surf the internet and do programming in React Native, Python, Docker etc. I want to know if there is any Dependency related issues with Ubuntu 17.10 or is it ready for development purpose also. Please help me decide which one should I go with.

Answer (score 2):

I'm just a desktop end user, but I would stick with 16.04 since it's the stable long term supported [(LTS) version](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS).  It should have the least likely chance of dependency issues since many vendors standardize on it knowing it will be supported for 3 years.

The next LTS, 18.04, is due out this April therefore there is a ton of development going on to 17.10 that will culminate into 18.04.

Comment: fyi:  Ubuntu LTS 16.04 has five years of support for everything in the 'main' repo (or everything on the official install iso)

Comment: If he is using MATE for example, it is 3 years. 5 years only the main Ubuntu LTS release!

Answer (score 2):

16.04 is a LTS (Long-Term Support) version and is more stable than 17.10, which has 9-month support only against 5 years from LTS (Ubuntu flavors might have different EOL).

Usually some developers want to have access to the most recent features and packages, so that would be good to stick with 17.10, but that means after July 2018 you will have to upgrade your computer to get access to software updates - 17.04 release ended its life by January 13th, 2018.

If you don't want to upgrade your computer every 9 month and the software available in 16.04 is OK for you then stick with 16.04.

Check also the Ubuntu release page: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Answer (score 1):

I'd choose Ubuntu 16.04 as it has the long-term support meaning its bugs are fixed and the system is overall stable.

Anyway, 18.04 version with the long-term support as well is going to come out soon, so it'd make sense to wait for it and upgrade from 16.04.